# How can I count only 'Yes' entities in my column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, count, data-visualization

In Input[96] I tried many things but couldnot do anything, always getting both 'yes, and 'no values'

Input:

```
y = (z_copy['fruity']) .value_counts()
print(y)
```

Output:

```
No     45
Yes    38
Name: fruity, dtype: int64
```

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text in question, not image.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Because `value_counts()` returns `Series` so you can use `['Yes']`

```
print( z_copy['fruity'].value_counts()['Yes'] )
```

.

```
import pandas as pd

z_copy = pd.DataFrame({'fruity': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']})

print( z_copy['fruity'].value_counts()['Yes'] )
```

---

**OLD VERSION:** You can get selected rows and use `len()`

```
import pandas as pd

z_copy = pd.DataFrame({'fruity': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']})

filter = (z_copy['fruity'] == 'Yes')
selected = z_copy[filter]

print( len( selected ) )

#print( len( z_copy[df['fruity'] == 'Yes'] ) )
```

Eventually you can use `sum()` because `True/False` is converted to `1/0`

```
filter = (z_copy['fruity'] == 'Yes')

print( sum( filter ) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... I tried myself and came to a more compact code:     z_copy[z_copy['fruity'] == 'Yes']['fruity'].value_counts()

Comment: Now I released that you can use `['Yes']` in `z_copy['fruity'].value_counts()['Yes']` because `value_counts()` returns `Series`